# GM_getResourceURL not working for binary object, in Firefox, but works in Tampermonkey?

Tags: base64, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

In Tampermonkey, the following code to add an audio element with base64 data from an OGG resource works fine:

```
var m = GM_getResourceURL("music") || null;
$("html").append('<audio id="audio" autoplay loop src="data:audio/ogg;base64,' + m + '" />')
```

In Greasemonkey, `m` is not the base64 string, it's some UUID followed by the name of the resource. How can I take the actual base64 data from the resource and use it like I can in Tampermonkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GM_getResourceURL()` currently behaves very differently in Greasemonkey versus Tampermonkey.

- In **Greasemonkey**, [a special **protected URL** is provided for the file](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceURL#Returns).
- **Tampermonkey** still follows the old way of [**base64 encoding** the file](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_getResourceURL) and serving that.
  (Note that Greasemonkey *used* to behave the same way before GM version 1.0.)

I'd say this is a bit of a bug with Tampermonkey because it's way more efficient to serve the resource directly off the disk, than to: read it, base64 encode it, and then have the browser have to base64 decode it to use it.

Anyway, here is a complete working script that functions in both Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Using a binary resource
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @resource    musicFile  https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2587/AudioTest%20%281%29.ogg
// @grant       GM_getResourceURL
// ==/UserScript==

var musicResrc = GM_getResourceURL ("musicFile");

/*--- GM_getResourceURL() currently behaves very differently in Greasemonkey versus Tampermonkey.
    In Greasemonkey, a special protected URL is provided to the file.
    Tampermonkey still follows the old way of base64 encoding the file and serving that.

    The GM URL looks like:
        greasemonkey-script:402c80a8-c313-439c-9d7b-c9bdc52b7b02/musicFile
*/

if (typeof musicResrc === 'string'  &&  musicResrc.slice(0, 12) === "greasemonkey") {
    console.log ("Greasemonkey mode.");
}
else {
    console.log ("Tampermonkey mode.");
    musicResrc  = 'data:audio/ogg;base64,' + musicResrc;
}
//console.log ("musicResrc: ", musicResrc);

$("body").prepend (
    '<div><audio type="audio/ogg" src="' + musicResrc + '" autoplay="true" loop="true" controls="true"></audio></div>'
);
```

Note that some (all? my?) installations of Firefox will not autoplay audio this way. (And [it's generally a very poor practice](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/video-usability/).)

Comment: What would you suggest is a better way to load and play audio cross domain? Also, my code had a typo. I'm using GM_getResourceURL, and my code works in Tampermonkey but not Greasemonkey.

Comment: Your code works in Firefox, but it doesn't autoplay in Chrome/Tampermonkey.

Comment: Thank you for this - I eventually did something similar in my code, accounting for both TM and GM. Thanks Brock, as always.